# C# DDD pattern inquiry on Aggregates

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new with DDD so please bear with me.

Scenario
Aggregate A and 
Aggregate B

A is related to B by relationId which is on Aggregate B (so it will be B.A_Id
Now, I have to create B but there's a rule that I can't create B if B.SalesDate is closer than 7 calendar days from A.ReleaseDate. My question is on my CommandHandler on Aggregate B, can I do a query on Aggregate A to get A.ReleaseDate so I can do the process on checking if the provided B.SalesDate is not closer than 7 calendar days? this is part of the code on CommandHandler use on Aggregate B:

```
public async Task Handle(AddBCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!command.IsValid())
            {
                NotifyValidationErrors(command);
                return;
            }
// this is where I do a query on Aggregate A to get details using the Id (which is A.Id from Aggregate A) selected on UI
            var aggregateADetails = await A_Repository.GetFirstAsync(x => x.Id == command.Id);



            //if (isCloserthan7Days.)
            //{
            //    NotifyError(string.Empty, "B.SalesDate is 7 days closer than A.ReleaseDate");
            //    return;
            //}
```

so on this CommandHandler, I instantiate 2 repository, 1 for B and 1 for A to be use on the query. Will I violate a rule on DDD by doing that? Sorry, it's not that clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command handler is considered application layer and not domain layer.

Considering above, it is perfectly fine to load aggregate A from command handler and push data into aggregate B, but logic has to be implemented in domain layer, which that means an aggregate B method. In general what application layer does (if you thinkg about it) is retrieve all the data required by a domain layer method to do its work. It is irrelevant that the data required is (in this case) from another aggregate. Semantically it is the same as if you were reading a property from a read-model projection of that aggregate and it is fine with regards to "rules" of DDD (although in case you are considering to read from asynchronously generated projections you should be aware of possibility of introducting eventual consistency issues). The important thing to remember is that even if you are OK to read from aggregate A, inside the scope of this change, you should only edit (and save) one aggregate.

Something I did not mention in my original answer, but should have, and was pointed by Constantine in comments is the issue of consistency. While reading from query stores (as I commented above) may introduce eventual consistency issues, reading data from another aggregate may also introduce consistency issues since you are reading data from aggregate A that may be stale by the time that aggregate B finished operations and attempts to get persisted.

(Reply to EDIT): In your code sample your method is a combination of application layer and domain layer logic. Loading from repos is app layer, but logic to decide if you should be acting in the aggregate should belong inside the aggregate. I may be missing some info here, but from what little I see at this point, I'm guessing you probably have an aneamic domain model. Regardless of this, my initial response still applies.

Comment: Yup, Aggregate A will just be use to get A.ReleaseDate and use it for validation purposes on the command handler, the rest of the logic on saving is on Aggregate B which is on the domain level.

Comment: You should add to yiur answer the important note that this rule is  checked in an *eventually consistent* manner.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Maybe I am not being very clear and should update the answer to this end, but I am not suggesting that one uses an asyncrhronously generated read model. I was just saying that loading an aggregate to _read_ a value is behaviourally and semantically similar to reading from a projection.

Comment: @SKleanthous yes, I know, but business rules that use data from other Aggregates are (as in "should") be eventually consistent and the developer must be aware of this. The architecture (Classic or CQRS) is irrelevant.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yes you are right. I will amend the answer.